# Are elliptic curves algebraic varieties?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, elliptic-curves

I got a short question.

Are elliptic cubes also algebraic varietes?

Say we have $E:y^2=x^3+5x=:f(x)$

Then we can $f(x)=x(x^2+5)$

So it can't be an algebraic variety..

I feel like I am totally misunderstanding the definition of algebraic varieties.

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: You mean, because it's not irreducible? Well, some authors consider this property to be part of the definition, others don't. From my point of view, yes they are. Others would call them "algebraic sets".

Comment: If your question is on the difference between algebraic *sets* and algebraic *varieties*, then whilst your $f$  will only define a set, it doesn't actually correspond to an elliptic curve. The one given in my answer is in fact irreducible (a necessary condition for elliptic curves) so does give a variety.

Answer (score 4):

Elliptic curves are very famous examples of algebraic varieties. You seem to have forgotten that the function can have more than one variable; take the function $f(x,y)=y^2-x(x^2+5)$, then $E$ is just the variety $V(f)$.

Comment: Yes, your are right..I forgot this. But why f(x,y) is irreducible? Why it is irreducible in any case? Since f(x,y) must be irreducible for all elliptic curves..Its because every elliptic curves is smooth?

Comment: Try writing $f(x,y)=(y-ax^2+bx+c)(y-dx^2+ex+f)$ and show that this cannot happen. As to why it "splits" this way, since $f$ is quadratic in $y$, if it factorises then both factors must be linear in $y$.

Comment: An elliptic curve is defined to be a smooth projective irreducible variety of dimension 1 (so it is a curve) and genus 1.

Comment: But the definition I use is just based on a weierstrass polynomial and the condition that its not singular.

Comment: That is a perfectly valid definition, mine is just defined more abstractly :) The non-singular condition equates to being smooth and the factorisation issue relates to being irreducible. Also yours should have a point at infinity in the definition which is a consequence of it being a projective variety.

Answer (score -2):

You are messing up the notation and confusing yourself. You could write the polynomial
$$
f(x) = x^3 + 5x \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \text{ or } \mathbb{C}[x]
$$
or you could write the polynomial
$$
f(x,y) = y^2 - x^3 - 5x \in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]
$$
Once you factor $f(x)$ you find that it equals $x(x^2 + 5) = x(x+i\sqrt{5})(x-i\sqrt{5})$. This should give you the hint that it defines a single point in $\mathbb{Q}$ while giving you three distinct points in $\mathbb{C}$. The other polynomial does define an ellitpic curve as a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

Also, you could ramp up this discussion and frame it into a scheme theoretic language. Then, you should consider the scheme
$$
X = \text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 - 5x))
$$
If you write this as the functor $X = \text{Hom}_{\textbf{CRing}}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^2 - x^3 - 5x),-)$, then
\begin{align*}
X(\mathbb{F}_q) &= \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{F}_q^2: b^2 - a^3-5a =0 \} \\
X(\mathbb{Q}_p) &= \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}_p^2: b^2 - a^3-5a =0 \} \\
X(\mathbb{Q}) &= \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{Q}^2: b^2 - a^3-5a =0 \} \\
X(\mathbb{C}) &= \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{C}^2: b^2 - a^3-5a =0 \} 
\end{align*}
and so on...